# How to capture the remainder of a sentence after two word boundaries using python regex (example given)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

See python code. How do I define `result`  such that it returns everything after the second word boundary? In this case "THE REST OF THE SENTENCE WHICH COULD BE LONG"

```
import re
content = '!wordOne wordTwo THE REST OF THE SENTENCE WHICH COULD BE LONG' 
result= re.sub(r'^\W*\w+\W*', '', content)
```

I'm stuck because the code above is returning "wordTwo THE REST OF THE SENTENCE WHICH COULD BE LONG". Ideally I want it to return "THE REST OF THE SENTENCE WHICH COULD BE LONG"

Requirements:

- !wordOne will always start with a ! followed by \w characters
- wordTwo will always be bound by white spaces and will consist of \w
  characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'^!\w+\s+\w+\s+', '', content)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QusC0W/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `!` - a `!` char
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\s+\w+\s+` - 1+ whitespaces, 1+ word chars, 1+ whitespaces.

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E!%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2B):

[image]

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/QDZSx7):

```
import re
content = '!wordOne wordTwo THE REST OF THE SENTENCE WHICH COULD BE LONG' 
result= re.sub(r'^!\w+\s+\w+\s+', '', content)
print(result)
# => THE REST OF THE SENTENCE WHICH COULD BE LONG
```

Comment: Wonderful.  It works.  I will accept the answer soon